# Selecting which div class ruby should select? (using watir)

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm having an issue of selecting the content I want to store as a string, as the data has the same div class name and there is no set ID to use instead.

I'm aware of the first and last operator in ruby, but is there anyway to select the options in between?

So for example

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="example">1111</div>
        <div class="example">2222</div>
        <div class="example">3333</div>
        <div class="example">4444</div>
        <div class="example">5555</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get ruby to select the 4th class of the same class name, so I can store 4444 as my string?

Comment: Are you confusing ruby, CSS and javascript with each other?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, sorry I forgot to say I'm using watir for automated testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
browser.divs(:class => "example")[3]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way (using Watir API):

```
browser.div(:class => "example", :index => 3)
```